# Is it possible to allow only some users to access to Google Big Query API?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-bigquery

I have created a project with Google Big Query.

I have one table with data. A service performs insert every hour in the table. The service uses a service account with a p12 file to authenticate without user interaction.

I have developped also a desktop application which authenticate via the  browser (OAuth2Authenticator). It works well but eveyone who have a google account can login and accept to use my application, and I don't want that !

Is it possible to specify a list of authorized google accounts for a google big query project ?

Thanks,
   Luc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can control [who has access](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#aclsandrights) to your BigQuery datasets, as well as who is a member of the Google Developer Project that your BigQuery datasets are attached to.

If you are creating a Desktop application, the best way to provide authorization to BigQuery for specific users of a restricted dataset is to use an "[installed application](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp)" Oauth2 flow. Are you currently using this flow?